# Trying to push only key commits to git server

Tags: git, repository, push

I have a git repository on a server. I can pull or clone copies from it. In a working copy, I want to create a branch and do some work. So far so standard.

While doing that work, I may well perform several commits and even create some more temporary branches as I try out ideas. That is the git way of things as I understand it.

However, when I am happy with what I have done, I want to merge the new stuff into my master branch and push the result up to the server. What I **don't** want is all those temporary branches and intermediate commits in my server repository. I would like to see just one (or a small number of key) commit(s) on the server not every footling little thing I tried while doing the change.

I can't work how to do that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

- You can squash and reorder commits in a branch using [`git rebase -i master`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_interactive_mode), then merge it.

  See also documentation in [Git Book](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html), [GitHub](http://help.github.com/rebase/), [git ready](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html).
- Branches remain local unless *you* push them somewhere. If you push `master`, other branches won't get pushed automatically.